# Sign up with Google/Facebook/Twitter/LinkedIn

Tags: login, social-media

We need people to create an account so they can use our free trial. Afterwards we need to contact them if they want to buy the product, as there is no option of buying it online.

I have been trying to figure out which sign up buttons would be the best. For me it would be important to get real information, so I thought that signing up with Google and LinkedIn is the best option.

In your experience, what form of social sign in will provide us with the best quality information to use in our follow up?

Comment: Do you mean signup rather than sing up? At the moment, I don't understand your question.

Comment: What sort of site is it? Who are the users? What are the business requirements? What user data do you need, and why?

Comment: We need people to create the account so they can use our free trial. Afterwards we need to contact them if they want to buy the product, as there is no option of buying it online. Hope it is clear now.
And this is my first ever post here, so sorry for not being specific!

Answer (score 3):

- **Email**: Not everyone uses social networks, users should be able to signup using there email address.
- **Facebook & Twitter** are important signup methods since they cover not all but most of the internet users.
- **linkedin**: add this if great part of your targeted audience is corporate or your product have to do something with business, jobs, corporate etc.
- **Google+**: If you have the time and budget add this but compared to Facebook & twitter their users are far less.

Answer (score 1):

As from your question and response to JonW's questions, if you are providing a trial version and want the user to signup just for the purpose of contacting them again I think the signup can be avoided there. If you have to make the user signup for something there should be something more that you should be able to provide the user (other than a download like access to a members only segment in you site, portal, more information etc) and more important is that you make use of the information you actually make the user enter.

Instead you can just provide an option for the user to enter her/his email id with the download option itself. It can be a field that is required for the downloading the trial. If the user is merely there to try your application then she/he would not mind entering just an email id as compared to filling up a signup form.

Once again, if there is any other use/ purpose of the information that you capture at signup then there may be a change to this approach.

Answer (score 0):

As Imran Bughio writes, it should definitely be possible to signup using an email address.

The current trend of forcing users to sign up using an account from one of the surveillance networks, is absoutely horrible and hopefully will stop soon.

You could also place a contact form on your website and refere to this in the free trial. If the users think the product is useful they will contact you. I think there is a great risk of losing potential customers by nagging them with messages, telephone calls etc.

Answer (score 0):

Having a social signup/login isn't a bad idea and you should generally stick to what users are using, aka what is the likelihood of them having a Google+ account versus a LinkedIn account? You have to remember that having all these options doesn't automatically validate your idea to add them in the first place. Do you plan on measuring how many users actually use this feature? I ask in reference to Mailchimp's own look into how useful social logins worked on their site:

https://blog.mailchimp.com/social-login-buttons-arent-worth-it/

One thing to be wary of is the fact if you leverage logging in based on a social network, you are making any risks/weaknesses your own, degrading credentials over time.